# ELB, EC2, Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am configuring ELB with EC2 in AWS and run into "Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively" error to cause the instance out of service. I have checked,

1) as I m using 8080 for security check port and my path is "/index.html". I test the link `http://ec2DNSname:8080/index.html` in the browser, it returns,

```
Response header:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "150-1420697739000"
Date: Thu, 08 Jan 2015 06:16:21 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Jan 2015 06:15:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 150
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: keep-alive
```

2) In my EC2 config, I allow the the inbound TCP traffic on 8080 from any machines

Any other possible cause of failing the health check?

Thanks
Hammer

Comment: What is Source setting for the Security Group configuration?

Comment: it is Source Security Group: 
982702088483/default
Owner Alias: 982702088483
Group Name: default    anything I need to configure for it?

Comment: can you show me the rules, choice that ec2 instance, description, `view rules`, it will show you the real firewall setting for that instance.  Can you take the screen shot and put here?

Comment: Thanks BMW, when I click "view rules", I see the display is different from what I have configured in the security group. It looks like there are some syn issues. I change the rules in security group again and click save. After 1 min, the change is reflected and shown correctly under "view rules".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the page returns a 200 response, it should eventually pass the health check. The Health Check configuration includes the number of times a Health Check needs to return a good result and how often to check it. So, a Healthy count of 5 with a check every 30 seconds would take 2.5 minutes to return as Healthy.

If the HTTP health check is failing, try it with a TCP health check on port 8080.

Also, just in case, check that your VPC configuration allows a connection from the Load Balancer to the EC2 instance. This will be automatic if they are in the same Subnet, but Network ACLs can impact a connection between different Subnets.

Comment: assuming my port config is ELB 8080 -> EC2 8080 and healthy check port is 8080 http. For the source security, shall I enable, inbound , http:8080 to all, and outbound all traffic to all?

Comment: I tried, 1) change healthy port to tcp 8080, still fails. 2) I change to the security group to allow inbound http 8080, tcp 8080 to all. Both not working :(

Comment: On the Security Group associated with the EC2 instances, try allowing Inbound "All traffic" from "0.0.0.0/0" for testing purposes. This will remove the security group as a possible cause of the problem. If that works, then it's a matter of appropriately configuring the Security Group. If it doesn't work, then something else is the cause.

Comment: Thanks. John, mine is working now. It looks like there some syn issues that what I configure in security group is different from the one under "view rules". I change again and resave.

Comment: I can confirm that changing the "HTTP" health check to "TCP" health check resolved this issue for me. Thanks @John

Comment: For me, about 15 minutes later after launching the instance, issue was fixed automatically. I guess, initialization took some time.

Answer (score 0):

if u create a linux server then you only need to attache one index.html file to your server,then it will work with http as well as TCP.
please let me it works or not. or you check Troubleshoot a Classic Load Balancer: Health Checks (1st error).